# How to define the foreign key relationship?

Tags: python, django

I'm new to django and the database concepts.

I'm getting the 1042 error code when I'm trying to register student via frontend and don't know where my mistake is

if anyone can help that'd be great.

I tried different ways but none was beneficial.

I can add the student via the admin panel of django but cannot do the same via frontend.

[image: This is the screenshot here.]

**models.py**

```
class Session(models.Model):
    session = models.CharField(max_length=150, default=" ")
    def __str__(self):
        return self.session
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('datapage')
    
    
class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, primary_key = True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank = True)
    semester = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank = True)
    session_year = models.ForeignKey(Session, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)
```

**forms.py**

```
session_years = Session.objects.all()
session_year_list = []
for session_year in session_years:
    single_session_year = (session_year.id, session_year.session)
    session_year_list.append(single_session_year)

class StudentSignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    last_name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    username = forms.CharField(required=True)
    phone_number = forms.CharField(required=True)
    semester = forms.CharField(required=True)
    
    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        email = email.lower()
        if User.objects.filter(email__iexact=email).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError('A user has already registered using this email')
        return email
    
    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
        if User.objects.filter(email__iexact=username).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError('A user has already registered using this username')
        return username
    
    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'username']
        

    @transaction.atomic
    def save(self):
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.is_student = True
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data.get('first_name')
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data.get('last_name')
        user.email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        user.username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
        user.save()
        student = Student.objects.create(user=user)
        student.phone_number=self.cleaned_data.get('phone_number')
        student.semester=self.cleaned_data.get('semester')
        student.session_year=self.cleaned_data.get('session_year')
        student.save()
        return user
```

**views.py**

```
class StudentRegister(LoggedInRedirectMixin, CreateView):
    model = User
    form_class = StudentSignUpForm
    template_name = 'registration/user_register.html'

    def form_valid(self, form_class):
        user = form_class.save()
        return redirect('datapage')
```

Comment: You have to create the `Student` in one shot, at least you need to set `session_year` on creation.

Comment: It looks more like error 1048 to me

Comment: what is session here.. ? are you passing session_id from front end...? You have mapped session_year to a session object as FK.. so session obj is required to create a student

Answer (score 0):

@Vatsai Vohera - Correct me if I am wrong.

```
 session = Session.objects.get(session=self.cleaned_data.get('session_year')
    student.session_year = session
```

Comment: @VatsalVohera- Can you print the logs by adding the code that I mentioned. Something like print(session)

Comment: code gets stuck after the ```student = Student.objects.create(user=user)``` line

Comment: @VatsalVohera= Does it throw an error in this line or ?

Comment: yes after this line, the code throws error.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding your requested data into session_year field which is not working rather you have to save your requested data to your model Session field session. I hope this will work for you.

Comment: I don't understand can you help me more?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `related_name='...'` field in your ForeignKey attribute
and also add this:

```
session_year = models.ForeignKey(Session,related_name='some thing', on_delete = models.CASCADE, null = True)
```

then you have to call session_year by related name